# Getting values of table section on mouse click jquery

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I have a div section which is draggable, when clicked it should go through all specified rows in the droppable section of the page. And if the draggable value is same as the value in the row, make the area not droppable.

this is what I've tried so far:

```js
$j('.dragCell').on('click', function(e) {
  var fin = $j(this).text().replace(/[\t\n]+/g, ' '); //draggable elem
  $j('.zoneHeader').each(function(index) { //go through the droppable
    var theHeader = $j('.zoneHeader')[index].val(); //droppable elemnt.. gives error: $j(...)[index].text is not a function
    var theZoneHeader = $j('.zoneHeader')[index]; //However this returns a <td> elem as:
    //<td class="dataCell  zoneHeader" id="j_id0:j_id4:photoBlock:j_id8:col1:availabilityRows:0:j_id10" colspan="1">Sophie Antoniou [Z2]</td>
    console.log(theHeader); //.find('.zoneHeader').html());
    //if(theZoneHeader !== fin){
    //get child of this(theZoneHeader) and make removeClass('droppable');
    //}
  });
});
```

Please let me know if i should provide more details i.e. html.. thx

Comment: please add an example link so that we can check and let you know the solution

Comment: .val() is a jQuery function, however [index] returns a javascript object. try $j(.zoneHeader).eq(index).val();

Comment: @BalázsVarga it works using .text(). cheers